# C# - DotNetZip - Create a brand new folder or file in archive

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, compression, dotnetzip

I am working on a project which creates a compressed zip file and then adds a few new files and folders into it. I have searched the internet for some while now and can't find a solution. I am using *.NET Framework 4.7.1.* in *Visual Studio 2017*.

Here is what I have tried:

```
private void CreateFile(string saveDirectory)
{
    using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
    {
        zip.Password = "Some Password";
        zip.Encryption = EncryptionAlgorithm.WinZipAes256;
        zip.Save(saveDirectory);
    }
}

private void ConfigureFile(string loadDirectory)
{
    using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(loadDirectory))
    {
        zip.AddDirectory("Folder 1");
        zip.AddDirectory("Folder 2");
        zip.AddDirectory("Folder 3");
        zip.AddFile("File 1");
        zip.AddFile("File 2");
    }
}
```

But it searches the directory of the project for that file, and throws a `Not Found` error. I also tried creating the folder or file in some place on the hard drive, and then placing it into the zip file, but **is there a way to create a file or folder straight into the zip file without?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can create a `ZipEntry` which doesn't rely on the corresponding path or file name existing, you can provide the content yourself. For example:

```
public void ConfigureFile(string loadDirectory)
{
    using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(loadDirectory))
    {
        zip.AddEntry(@"Folder1\Test.txt", new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 });
        zip.Save();
    }
}
```